# Can a host containg only a JSON returned by a PHP file be injected?

Tags: php, code-injection, shared-hosting

I have a server which is been hacked several times. After deleting almost everything, now I only have some static files (html, js, jpg) an a single php that only returns a JSON array (not even `<?php ?>`). It could be `.json` perfectly.

Is it possible for some hacker to inject code anyway?
My hosting support insists that it is. I REALLY have my doubts but they don't want to take any responsibilities. Any idea?

(Sorry if this post doesn't follow any rule)

Here the chat:

```
 Chat ID: 41409607 Initial Question: Injections keep coming even I only have a single php file.. can you scan, please? Maybe there is a cron or something hidden?
 10:18:49 PM Chuck R Hello Mario, this is Chuck with Sitelock. usually this can happen with URL injection.
 10:19:15 PM Mario Morales againt what?
 10:19:26 PM Mario Morales I have only static pages
 10:19:41 PM Mario Morales and a php that returns a string. No code on it
 10:20:04 PM Mario Morales :(
 10:21:24 PM Chuck R There is a page, meaning it can be injected.
 10:23:46 PM Mario Morales even it has only a JSON on it?
 10:24:02 PM Chuck R Yes, unfortunately.
 10:24:18 PM Chuck R The only way for a site not be hacked is to not have it, or for it to be parked.
 10:26:17 PM Mario Morales Really?
 10:26:26 PM Mario Morales First time I heard that
 10:27:42 PM Chuck R Yes. Definitely is unfortunate but it's the way it is.
 10:29:01 PM Mario Morales I can't find an example of how a php file containing only "[{key:value},{key:value}]" can be injected.
 10:29:05 PM Mario Morales but ok
 10:29:39 PM Mario Morales Let me copy the chat and ask on some forum
 10:29:45 PM Chuck R Well it's happening.
```

Comment: What's the code in the PHP file?

Comment: why does your php file have json formatted data? is that not causing issues of its own? I am just curious as to how only a `[{key:value},{key:value}]` can reside inside a php file.

Comment: @coderodour Well if you don't enter `<?php` then essentially it's just raw data, like `.html` or `.json`.

Comment: typical hosting support their - not very smart. Not that its really their job

Comment: @DaveChen thanks. Je comprends. I'd guess it is still good practice to use a .json file when you have only json though.

Comment: My first thought would to make sure the web server does not have write access to the directory or files. Assuming thats where the files are getting changed from.

Comment: @coderodour  I had in my mind to insert some code, but at the I didn't. I saw that raw data was enough and I didn't saw a reason to change de extension. Yes, it could perfectly be a .json

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is 100% secure; even less with dynamic content -PHP or whatever.

If your server has been hacked several times:

- Change web hosting.
- Port your data -look for possible injections before, e.g. [persistent XSS](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/persistent-xss/),- not your code.
- Rewrite your code. Let's be honest, if they hacked your site several times, that means that the quality of the already existing code is not optimal.
- Don't try to code everything; you will get it wrong at the beginning. Use a framework or well known libraries for at least user management and database abstraction.

Comment: I had an un-mantained wordpress on it (a dev version from an old project). I assumed that was the main reason.

Comment: To serve a few static files -but have a website anyway- I would suggest [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/). Maybe the PHP code can be replaced with some pre-processing.